# How do you perform integration tests with NServiceBus?

Tags: c#, testing, nservicebus

I have Web Application that has 2 sets of services.  One set is business services like UserService and another set that is utility services like EmailService.   How the business services connect to the utility services is through NServiceBus.   How do you perform integration tests in this scenario?   What I've done right now is that I broke out the integration test to 2 unit tests.  First is testing the business service and then mock/verify out the NServiceBus send.  Second unit test is on the utility service and then mock/verify the email sending.    As you can tell, this isn't optimal at all.   Current we have 2 instances of NServiceBus -- one as client and one as server (server has addition of handlers).  This work in normal, non-test mode (since client is under the context of IIS and the server is a standalone app) but when I try to do this in test, it seems like I can't run two instances?  Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are doing Unit Testing correctly, by mocking out the external dependency on NServiceBus.  To be clear, my definition of unit tests is that they don't do anything outside of your code (like, say, using MSMQ).  For your integration tests, you should be able to get away with something very simple that proves that you are able to pass a message from one system to the other, and perhaps get the expected end result.  To set this up, you can actually launch the NServiceBus client/server from within the setup method of your test fixture (and dispose of them in the teardown).  It shouldn't matter whether they are EXEs or run within IIS - you should be able to programmatically start/stop them from within your test even if it means calling out to Process.Start() or something similar.

Alternately, if your integration tests are running on a build server as part of a continuous integration setup, your build script can ensure the proper processes are running prior to even launching your tests, which will likely result in more repeatable and faster results.  Using a combination of TeamCity and MSBuild or NAnt it is pretty easy to do something like this.

Comment: Hmmm, I would disagree that he is "doing Unit Testing correctly". Don't mock what you don't own. The fact that he needs to mock the NServiceBus indicates to me that he may not have properly abstracted away the dependency on the bus. In other words, high-level policy objects depend on low-level details. He should be able to unit test the objects in isolation, perhaps using a spy in place of the bus to observe the desired behavior of the objects, again, in isolation. (cont'd below)

Comment: (cont'd from above) Then, as he correctly observes, he should also have integration tests to test that the interactions between all actors (including the bus) are working as intended (e.g. messages are being sent/received by their respective objects as expected over the bus).